# Swipe-for-options UI component

Tags: gui-design, mobile

What is the name of the UI component in mobile, which when scrolled or swiped to the side reveals options like delete, edit, move etc. ?

Comment: I believe it is just called "inline swiping gestures".

Comment: This link confirms what @Jonathan Kempf is referring to. This is what Apple call it: 
http://appleinsider.com/articles/14/09/17/how-to-navigate-the-new-mail-gestures-and-data-features-in-ios-8

Answer (score 1):

In Material Design this interaction pattern/component is referred to as a **Leave-Behind**.

See reference here:https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/lists-controls.html#lists-controls-types-of-list-controls

> **Leave-behinds**
>
> A leave-behind is an informative hint as to what swiping a list item
>   away will do to that item. The leave-behind can transform into an
>   action.
>
> Swiping on a list item from either direction will reveal an icon
>   indicating the action. After swiping, a follow-up action can appear as
>   a text button within the space of the list item.